# How to show a checkbox when hovering over a div

Tags: html, css

I need to show a checkbox (which is hidden by default) when hovering over a div.
This is my html:

```
<div class="todoLeftImportance">
    <input type="checkbox" id="todoCheckbox">
</div>
```

When I hover over the 'todoLeftImportance' div I would like to show the 'todoCheckbox' that is inside of it. 
I've played around with "display: block" and "display: none" but I don't know how to link the div and checkbox together via css.

Comment: <style>.todoLeftImportance:hover #todocheckbox{ display:block }</style>

Answer (score 2):

Css for your reference, hope it help:

```
#todoCheckbox{
display: none;
}

.todoLeftImportance:hover #todoCheckbox{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: So simple, thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.todoLeftImportance{
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.todoLeftImportance:hover{
  opacity: 1.0;
}
</head>
</style>
<body>
<div class="todoLeftImportance">
    <input type="checkbox" id="todoCheckbox">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS

```
#todoCheckbox{ visibility: hidden; }                           
.todoLeftImportance:hover #todoCheckbox{ visibility: visible; }
```

Comment: css display block and none should also work

Comment: `visibility: hidden;` will not hide the element. It keeps the element in DOM and cannot be seen. All actions do work like onchange, onclick.

Comment: @Harish display hidden and visibility hidden are very similar. The only difference is, when display none is set, no space is allocated for the element whereas when visibility hidden is set, the element is physically present on the page but not visible. In my view, visibility hidden is a better method in this case.